# JQuery Dynatree - How to search node with level delimiter?

Tags: jquery, search, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I need to use a searching function for my dynatree and so I found this workaround: [JQuery Dynatree - search node by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277797/jquery-dynatree-search-node-by-name)

However, I need to have it search only up until my expanded node delimiter.
(I am using jQuery ui-slider to dynamically set the expand delimiter).
Initially, I need it to search until my minExpandedLevel. And if I move the slider, the dynatree should show **only matching results** in expanded level equivalent to the slider value.

Trying to reset the minExpandLevel and reloading the dynatree just wont do as it returns all(even non-matching) nodes as result.

So I want to add a limit parameter to the search function like:

> $(selector).dynatree("getRoot").search(pattern, limit);

Does anybody  know how to do this?

Here's my code:

**dynatree:**

```
$.ui.dynatree.nodedatadefaults["icon"] = false;

$("#resultTree").dynatree({
    minExpandLevel: 4,
    persist: false,
    classNames: {
        vline: "no-bg",
        connector: "",
        expander: "ui-helper-hidden"
    },
    children: myJsonData
});
```

**slider:**

```
timeout = false;
searchTerm = $("#searchText").val();
$("#treeslider").slider({
    min: minTick,
    max: maxTick,
    range: "min",
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#resultTree").dynatree("getRoot").search(searchTerm, ui.value);
        }, 500);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay, I think I found the answer:**

I modified the [_searchNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277797/jquery-dynatree-search-node-by-name) function so it will hide matching nodes greater than the level delimiter, but will show parent node(even non-matching) as long as the term matches within its children.

```
var clear = true;
DynaTreeNode.prototype.search = function (pattern,limit) {
if (typeof limit == "undefined") {
    limit = 0;
}

if (pattern.length < 1 && !clear) {
    clear = true;
    this.visit(function (node) {
        node.expand(true);
        node.li.hidden = false;
        node.expand(false);
    });
} else if (pattern.length >= 1) {
    clear = false;
    this.visit(function (node) {
        node.expand(true);
        node.li.hidden = false;
    });
    var searchDepth = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.childList.length; i++) {
        var hide = { hide: false };
        this.childList[i]._searchNode(pattern, hide, searchDepth, limit);
    }
}
},

// bottom-up node searching function
DynaTreeNode.prototype._searchNode = function (pattern, hide, searchDepth, limit) {
    var level = searchDepth;
    if (this.childList) {
        // parent node
        var hideNode = true;
        var searchDepth = level+1;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.childList.length; i++) {
            var hideChild = { hide: false };
            this.childList[i]._searchNode(pattern, hideChild, searchDepth, limit);
            hideNode = hideNode && hideChild.hide;
        }

        if (hideNode && !this._isRightWithPattern(pattern)) {
            this._hideNode();
            hide.hide = true;
        } else {
            if (limit && level > limit) {
                this._hideNode();
            }
            hide.hide = false;
        }

    } else {
        // leaf        
        if (!this._isRightWithPattern(pattern)) {
            this._hideNode();
            hide.hide = true;
        } else {
            if (limit && level > limit) {
                this._hideNode();
            }
            hide.hide = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this seems exactly what I'm after however I've absolutely no idea where to place this!  Can you give concise details as to which file (jquery.dynatree.js I presume) and whereabouts.

Comment: Don't think this warrants an 'answer', but have finally managed to find where to put this code.  For anyone else (and there are a few), look for the line "var DynaTree = Class.create();" and paste the above code after that.  It DOES work 100% :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of code that starts at the root and visits each node but doesn't process nodes at level 3 or lower:

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node){

    if( node.getLevel() > 2) {
        return 'skip';
    }

    console.log('processing node "' + node.data.title + '" at level ' + node.getLevel());

});
```

The visit function will stop processing a branch if you return the string **'skip'**.

Comment: oh thanks, this works for a top-down searching, but I need a bottom-up searching approach. That is why I need to utilize the [_searchNode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277797/jquery-dynatree-search-node-by-name) method. Now how do I search until the last node and hide em up if its greater than my level delimiter?

Comment: This way it will show the parent node that is <= delimiter even if only the last node matches the search term.